# Open sourcing a commercial site

Tags: language-agnostic, open-source

I am building a 'software as a service' website that will be charging users a small monthly fee. I am considering changing the Github repository over from Private to Public. Essentially open sourcing it. Is this suicide? I would like the community to be able to benefit from the code. It is unlikely that I will accept any push request so I'm not going to gain anything in that regard. It is community based, so I think most of the value would be lost by someone self hosting it. It is for a very niche audience so I doubt someone else will start a competing hosting. I would really like the code to be in the open, but not at the expense of my idea of course. How does everyone else feel about this? What is common practice?

Conclusion, I'm keeping it closed for the time being. I may look to open source sometime after launch however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, and this is not likely going to be a popular answer, but to myself, I would keep it closed for a period of time.

The reasons for this are simple, establish your foothold in the marketplace, build your userbase, your brand, then it gives you a mechanism to market your product further by selectively or completely open sourcing components of your system.

Comment: Because MySQL failed to establish a commercial basis whilst being open source (not counting the $1 billion purchase)? And many other examples

Comment: I don't respond to flame bait. Two reasonable people may disagree over given points, no need to take the position that it needs to be a religious battle. Please don't make it such.

Comment: @jer, not a religious battle! Simply disagreeing. it is only that your points don't come with evidence to back them up and are flawed; being closed source, in most situations, provides non of the advantages you state. Just look at the userbase, foothold, sometimes  profitability and branding of Mozilla Firefox vs IE, Apache vs IIS and so on.

Comment: @Aiden - MySQL is one product. 99% of companies do NOT open source. Microsoft Windows? Closed. Google search? Closed. Apple Mac? Closed. Banking systems? Closed. Your argument is BS.

Comment: @Coronatus - Settle down. I didn't say all companies are open source (or should be), only that being closed source isn't a blanket advantage for the points stated - therefore not a compelling reason to stay closed in itself.

Comment: Coronatus: As you said: "one product".  You picked 3 companies known for releasing a *huge* amount of open-source code, and then listed *one product* from each that's closed-source.  And while we're counting, MySQL AB had closed-source programs, too.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are not going to accept pushes you might as well hold on get your code stable and then publish it for others to learn and benefit from. You are still building the service, so its not going to attract too many eyeballs either.

From a business point of you, you might want to have a reasonable community around your service before you opensource it. if you are still budding who knows if its taken up by a stronger competitor. If your idea is patented its a different story.

Answer (score 5):

**I say do it for both personal benefit and potential strategic benefit ... afterall, alot of software IS a service**

Most open-source projects stand to provide a return *in the right circumstances*. Don't forget, unless you have a patent or some massive advance that is so complex and unfathomable that nobody can re-implement it .. **if they want to they will anyway**, so you have little protection staying closed source anyway ... even more interesting is that the open-source equivalent may well overtake your proprietary one if it garners support.

People may send you great ideas you never thought of, or take your codebase in a direction you would not have predicted. Unless you have significant *value* in terms of IP or strategic position tied up in the source code ... releasing it will probably do more good than harm.

Also, by being first to the open-source arena with your code, you gain control over any resulting community driven development ... if somone reimplemented your functionality and went open source ... could you compete on any front?

I know it is a cliche, but probably for good reason, but read **[The Cathedral and the Bazaar](http://catb.org/esr/writings/homesteading/)** and the essay [Open Source as a Signalling Device - An Economic Analysis](http://opensource.mit.edu/papers/leemoisaweiss.pdf) which is an interesting read. [Michael E. Porter's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Porter) texts on competition analysis are interesting when held up against the mixed value economics and competitive forces of open source and shows how disruptive open-sourcing a product can be to competitors ... and how it can add value to your market position. Also, whilst counterintuative, it can raise the barriers to a successful entry by competitors.

More food for thought on the advantages and *disadvantages* of open sourcing:

1. [What the DoD thinks of open source](http://powdermonkey.blogs.com/files/2009oss.pdf1)
2. [Alfred H. Essa "Innovation and strategic advantage: lessons from open source"](http://www.inderscience.com/search/index.php?action=record&rec_id=13226&prevQuery=&ps=10&m=or) (warning, journal link)

Comment: The "What the DoD thinks of open source" link should be http://powdermonkey.blogs.com/files/2009oss.pdf .

Answer (score 3):

I like to fix flaws wherever I see them, and perhaps I am one of your users. I'd rather send a patch than send a potentially nagging-sounding email any day.

Answer (score 2):

What benefit are you hoping to gain from making the code open source? If you don't want the input of other developers then there are very few advantages and a whole lot of potential disadvantages.

Comment: I guess I just like the idea of it being available if someone wants to see it. It's probably a little idealistic. I think it would be cool for a user if they were curious. The advantage to me I guess is nothing, but if I can put it out there without losing anything I would like to.